# Stuck with a css assignment

Tags: html, css

All right, apologies about the vague title, the problem in question is far more specific. I am attempting something very simple: To place a paragraph of text neatly next to an image. In [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0z5g9rc9x3pt8hm/testZone.7z?dl=0) you can find a PDF of the assignment, complete with screenshots of how the finished product should look like. [This link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1r3o8xfuihzio7b/testZone.7z?dl=0) lets you download a zip file which contains everything related to this and more, but I will put the code snippets here too.

HTML code

```css
body
{
    font-family: "Segoe", sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8125em;
}
    
h1
{
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #FF0000;
}
    
h2
{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #575757;
}
    
h1+p
{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #575757;
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
    border-color: #575757;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}
    
body, h1, h2, p
{
    margin: 0;
}
    
img
{
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
.top
{
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #FF0000;
    padding: 1em;
}
    
.bot
{
    border-bottom: solid #FF0000;
}
    
.footer
{
    font-size: 1.2307692307692308em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #575757;
    background-color: #D9D9D9;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
    <img src="../../assets/logo.png" alt="logo">
    <h1>Main heading</h1>
    <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
    
<!-- alaosa -->
<div class="bot">
    <h2>Subheading</h2>
    <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p> 
    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
</div>
    
<!-- footer -->
<p class="footer">ITIY3 | SIS | UTA</p>
```

I cannot post more than two links, but I hope everyone can get the 7z open. Now, the thing is, I don't think I'm allowed to alter the html too much since the assignment is all about CSS and html file was provided, along with the image. Only thing I did to alter the html file was to make the src attribute so that the picture is found since I have a specific folder structure for these things, and I also added the classes to divs. However, I don't think I'm alowed to make any more divs, and this should be doable just by altering the CSS file. To find the HTML file, unpack the 7z and go to "TestZone/code/tehtava-3/tehtava3.html", the CSS file can be found in the same folder.

I'll be AFK for a while but I'll try to clarify anything you might be wondering about.

And sorry for this being such a mess.

Comment: No, we will not be downloading any files to do your assignment for you while you're AFK…

Comment: Do your own homework. And what makes you think we can all decipher PDFs written in Finnish all of a sudden?

Comment: I don't think that the real problem is the fact that the user is "AFK" or that the files are in Finnish. Why would someone go to the trouble of downloading a file from an unknown person/user?

Answer (score 0):

We will not be downloading any files to do your assignment for you while you're AFK.